# How to catch facebook crawler with httprequest.useragent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

As per facebook documentation to catch facebook crawler the request should be check against some user agent strings like `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` and `facebot`. 
However I was able to detect facebook crawler within my controller with `facebookexternalhit/1.1` before but this seems not working now.
Here is how I detect facebook crawler.

```
if (userAgent != null && userAgent.Contains("facebookexternalhit/") || userAgent.Contains("facebot") || userAgent.Contains("facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"))
            {
                return View(actionlinks);
            }
```

Is there anything changed on facebook side or I am missing something?

Comment: Simply make a debug output and check what User Agent your script receives …?

Comment: The request goes from the application to facebook and back from facebook to the application how can I debug it? I mean locally there is no way to debug the code I have to deploy it then watch it

Comment: Write debug outputs to the server log, or a text file ...